# Replace Null columns in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

I want to add a column named `CategoryCode` which would take the first 3 letters of `Category` column + the first 3 letters of `Subcategory` column+ any number.
The problem is that I have some values in `CategoryCode` column which I don't have to change. I just have to operate on values which is null.
Can anyone help me with that? It would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a Derived Column that replaces the input `CategoryCode` column using the following expression:

```
REPLACENULL([CategoryCode],LEFT([Category],3) + LEFT([SubCategory],3) + "123")
```

#### Update 1 - Adding an auto increment number

Unfortunately, SSIS Derived Column cannot be used to add an auto increment or randomly generated number. To achieve that you need to use a Script Component transformation:

```cs
if(row.CategoryCode_IsNull == true)
    row.outCategoryCode = row.Category.Substring(0,3) + row.SubCategory.Substring(0,3) + id.toString();
else
    row.outCategoryCode = row.CategoryCode;
```

**More detailed examples:**

- [Derived column Transformation Editor - I need add number at the end of order number in increment order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56585624/derived-column-transformation-editor-i-need-add-number-at-the-end-of-order-num/56587288#56587288)
- [Add incremental number while inserting records using SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378058/add-incremental-number-while-inserting-records-using-ssis/48378895#48378895)
- [HOW TO ADD A ROWNUMBER TO A DATA FLOW TASK IN SSIS 2012](https://hansmichielscom.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/how-to-add-a-rownumber-to-a-data-flow-task-in-ssis-2012/)

Comment: But I have to increase the numeric part for every record. It's like Category code would be my primary key.

Comment: What is your data source? Are you reading from SQL? @ADITYANARAYAN

Comment: The question is like... There is one category.txt file with CategoryCode, category and subcategory column. There is another Product table with product descriptions, price, category and subcategory column. We have to merge both files on the basis of categoryCode such that Category code becomes primary key in Category table and becomes foreign key reference to Product table.

Comment: @ADITYANARAYAN you need to use a Script Component to add an incremental number. I added several examples to my answer